# Printing string using Arrays of Pointers

Tags: c

Trying to revise for a coding exam and I came across this slide. Can any of you help me to understand how to print the strings from a pointer to array? Here is the code sample:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    size_t i;
    const char *suit[4] = { "Hearts", "Diammonds", "Clubs", "Spades" };

    printf("The strings in array const char*suit[4] is:\n\n");


    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        printf("const char *suit[%u] is: %s\n", i, suit[i]);
    }
}
```

When I print, I get this output:

```
The strings in array const char*suit[4] is:

const char *suit[0] is: Hearts
const char *suit[1] is: Diammonds
const char *suit[2] is: Clubs
const char *suit[3] is: Spades
```

However, it came with this error as well.
"Exception thrown at 0x7AAD170C (ucrtbased.dll) in Pointer Practice.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xCCCCCCCC."

Why is there an error? How do I print the same output, but without an error?

Thank you in advance guys!

Comment: As you can see in your output, the largest index is 3. Your loop is trying to access index 4 which does not exist. Why do you think that you need to do that?

Comment: I have no excuses.

Comment: Thank you for helping me to spot my error!

Comment: @FermiToh `printf("const char *suit[%u] is: %s\n", i, *suit[i]);` This can't be the real code. `*suit[i]` is a `char` and printing it with format `%s` can never result in those strings you quote.

Comment: @dxiv

Yes apologies! It should not have that '*'! Thank you so much for spotting it!

Answer (score 2):

A simple fix! You only have 4 elements in your array but are iterating 5 times. Trying to access `suit[5]` will throw a Segmentation Fault (on Linux) or an Access Violation (on Windows). These errors occur when your accessing memory you shouldn't be (if you tried to access 0xEABCC8, but you don't have access to it, you will get hit with one of these errors).
Try changing your max bound to 4, instead of 5.
In C (and basically every other language) indexes start at 0 when indexing, but start at 1 when initalisation. Example:

```c
const int foo[4] = { 6, 9, 3, 2}; // Creates an array with 4 elements.
foo[4] // Gets the fifth element since it start at zero,
foo[0] // thus this is the first element.
```

Comment: _Trying to access  suit[5]_ I think you mean _Trying to access  suit[4]_

Comment: @Milo Banks
Yep! Basic mistake! :(

Might I also ask another question? 

What does *suit[4] mean? Is it a POINTER to an ARRAY?

And inside the Array are strings.

Does each character in the string have it's own memory location? Or does the string itself take one memory location (but of course a larger memory)?

Comment: @FermiToh Certainly! Well, suit is an array with a length of four. The type of data that suit contains are strings, which in and of themselves are an array (this time of characters). Thus *suit[4] means your taking the 4th string inside of the suit array, and the `*` symbol just returns a pointer to that. So in the end, you end up getting a pointer to an array of characters (aka. you get a pointer to a string). As far as I know, you shouldn't have to supply the `*` character. C should devolve it for you.

Comment: @Abra Yes, indeed I do. It's late!

Comment: I see! So it's a POINTER to an ARRAY containing an ARRAY of characters (a string). Also, what about the memory location? If I am not wrong, each character in the string has it's own memory location right?

Comment: @FermiToh Yep! Think of each character as an int (that's what it actually is anyway). So the suit array is an array of pointers each pointing to the starting location of a string (which is pointing to the starting location of an array of characters, each of which has their own memory location). Also, please consider upvoting if this helped (not sure if I can ask this, if not, I'll remove this part)!

Comment: @MiloBanks

Thank you so much! May I know, how can you then refer to EACH element in the string array? Let's say I want to print the address of 'H' 'e' 'a' 'r' 't'? Each alphabet (element) should have it's own address. P.S Upvoted your comments :')

Comment: Simple. In order to get each character one after the other, just loop over the string. If you want to get the size of the string on the fly so you know how long to iterate, simply: `strlen(suit[i])`. So `for (int l = 0; l < strlen(suit[i]); l++) { printf("%c\n", suit[i][l]) }`. Note that strlent is only for getting the length of strings, and if you want to get the length of an array, google it.

Comment: Thank you so much, definitely gained a deeper understanding of pointers with your help!

Answer (score 1):

The largest index is 3. Your loop is trying to access index 4 which does not exist..

Sigh.

Answer (score 1):

As you found that, in your code, the loop which is printing `suit` array strings is accessing array beyond its size.
To not to repeat this mistake again, follow this mechanism to get the size of an array:

```
size_t sz = sizeof (arr) / sizeof (arr[0]);
```

In your case, you should do:

```
    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof (suit) / sizeof (suit[0]); ++i)
    {
        printf("const char *suit[%zu] is: %s\n", i, suit[i]);
    }
```

With this, if you change the size of `suit` array (adding or removing array members), you don't need to make any changes in the loop printing the `suit` array members.

---

**Additional**:

You don't need to specify the dimension when initialising an array. When we omit the dimension, compiler computes it for us based on the size of the initialiser. So, you can do:

```
const char *suit[] = { "Hearts", "Diammonds", "Clubs", "Spades" };
                ^^
                 |
           omit the dimension
```

To check it, you can do

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    const char *suit[] = { "Hearts", "Diammonds", "Clubs", "Spades" };

    printf ("Size of suit array : %zu\n", sizeof (suit) / sizeof (suit[0]));

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Size of suit array : 4
```

Answer (score 0):

As many have pointed out, you are trying to access an element in the array that is not there.

You also need to change the print line to the following, as you are printing the string itself, and you are already de referencing the pointer by suit[i].

```
for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    printf("const char *suit[%lu] is: %s\n", i, suit[i]);
}
```